# How to sum only one textbox value and show result in label in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

The question could be duplicate but my problem is totally different.

I have a one textbox and one label.

Example: label text is already exist with number like 450 Now I want to add number in textbox and the textbox value should be sum in 450 + 30 = 480 where 30 is textbox value.

what I have tried:

```
lbl_TotalAmount.Text = lbl_TotalAmount.Text + txt_DeliveryCharges.Text;
```

The above Result is: `45030`

Another Code I Have tried:

```
double total = Convert.ToDouble(lbl_TotalAmount.Text);
double charges = Convert.ToDouble(txt_DeliveryCharges.Text);
double sum = total + charges;
lbl_TotalAmount.Text = String.Format(sum.ToString("0.00"));
```

The above code is going to sum every value that I put in the textbox and also when I remove one word the number is sum every time.

Please give me best solution I tried many solution to solve this but unable to do this.

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: _"The question could be duplicate but my problem is totally different"_ Lol

Comment: Your last example seems to be likely to work OK - lbl_TotalAmount.Text = sum.ToString("0.00") will print the valeu of the variable "sum" to the label. Does it show anything ? (There is no need to call String.Format there)

Comment: Your second attempt is correct(ish)... you need to explain what's wrong with it (note that this has garnered 3 "unclear what you are asking" close votes so far)

Comment: If you want the program to 'remember' what the previous value that was entered, then you should somehow store the previous entries in a dictionary or something.

Comment: Second attempt result is 450 + 30 when I press 3 it sums 453 and then press 30 it adds 453 + 30 = 483 and when I remove 0 it agains sum 3 in 483.

Comment: You want that the 450 stays and is not overwritten by the sum? Easy: Then don't overwrite it but use a different label for the sum-result and you keep your original value in the first label. Or store the original value in a field in your class/form. It's rarely a good idea to use controls as replacement for variables. Their purpose is to display not to store something. Especially because you sometimes format or translate values and you always have to parse them to their real type.

Comment: Maybe you also handle the wrong event. Do the calculation when the user clicks a button and not presses a key.

Comment: I can do this with button click but I want to sum it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The above code is going to sum every value that I put in the textbox and also when I remove one word the number is sum every time.

That's most likely because you're calling your code inside the `TextChanged` or the `KeyPress` events of the textbox; this means that every time you modify *anything* in your textbox, your code will fire and make the sum.

Instead, add a button and put your code inside its `Click` event, or if you want the sum to respond to every keypress while respecting your original value, save your value in a variable and use it to calculate the sum.

```
'Declare a variable at form level
 Dim originalValue as Double

'Code where you put your value in a label, put it also in a variable
lbl_TotalAmount.text = 450
originalValue = 450

'Modify your code to use the original value instead of the label
double charges = Convert.ToDouble(txt_DeliveryCharges.Text);
double sum = originalValue + charges;
lbl_TotalAmount.Text = String.Format(sum.ToString("0.00"));
```

Comment: Checked in `KeyPress` but same result.

Comment: is there any way to do it directly because on button click it working fine.

Comment: Just to be clear: let's use your example and say that your label has `450`, and if the user presses 3 it should have `453` and then the user presses 0 (30) it should have `480` and if the user presses another 0 (300) it should show `750`; is that correct?

Comment: Yes it is correct

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer to adress that.

Answer (score 1):

Your strings need to be converted (parsed) to doubles (since they are representing monetary values), but you need to be sure that you're not trying to parse something that can't be converted.  TryParse() evaluates to true (or false if the parse fails), so you can avoid a possible exception.

Additionally, you've stated in comments that you want this to update as the text box is updated, so you'll need a variable that is out of scope to keep the total separated from the calculation.  I'm going to work from the assumption that this is a shopping cart, or something like that.  In that case, a List<> would be an obvious way to store the values of the items in the cart.

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic; //required for List<>

namespace WidowsFormsApplication
{
    public class ShoppingCart
    {
        List<double> shoppingCart = new List<double>();

        protected void AddItemToCart()
        {
            shoppingCart.Add(450);
        }

        protected void UpdateShoppingCart()
        {
            double total = 0;
            foreach (double item in shoppingCart) //calculate total of shoppingCart
            {
                total += item;
            }
            if (Double.TryParse(txt_DeliveryCharges.Text, out double charges))
            {
                total += charges; //add charges without altering shoppingCart
                lbl_TotalAmount.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", total);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Same result as my second solution :(

Comment: I think the answer given by Josh Part is at work.  I think it would be a good idea to add a button and attach this code to fire with a button click event.

Comment: my second solution works fine on button click but I want to do this directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
lbl_TotalAmount.Text = lbl_TotalAmount.Text + txt_DeliveryCharges.Text;
```

lbl_TotalAmount.Text and txt_DeliveryCharges.Text are text fields. You cannot do arithmetic on text fields. You have to convert to number, do the arithmetic then convert back

```
var charge = Int32.Parse(txt_DeliveryCharges.Text);
var total = Int32.Parse(lbl_TotalAmount.Text);
var newTotal = charge + total;
lbl_TotalAmount.Text = newTotal.ToString();
```

Comment: `String was not in a correct format` looks like same result as my 2nd solution.

Comment: ok, so engage brain. Look at the contents of the fields in a debugger. what do they contain, why are they not valid string to be parsed to a number

Answer (score 0):

> what you are doing is string concatenation

Not a sum of two numbers, You have to convert your strings to int first

here is how you can do that

```
int x = 0, y = 0;

if (Int32.TryParse(lbl_TotalAmount.Text out x) && Int32.TryParse(txt_DeliveryCharges.Text, out y))
{
    // you know that the parsing attempt
    // was successful
    lbl_TotalAmount.Text = x + y;
}
```

Comment: Nothing happening with this code.

Answer (score -1):

```
yourlabel.Text = ""+ (Int32.Parse(yourlabel.Text)+Int.Parse(your textbox.Text));
```

or

```
 yourlabel.Text = ""+(Double.Parse(yourlabel.Text)+Double.Parse(yourtextbox.Text));
```

are you using a double? only need that for decimal numbers that are super precise. whole numbers, use int... if you're using it to do money you want to use Decimal, but it depends on the situation.

Comment: Parse dude parse. its how you get an int from a string

Comment: Same result as my 1st solution.

Comment: ""+ (Int32.Parse(yourlabel.Text) That would always ends in string concatenation.